# Calling exe entry point from my code

Tags: c++, windows

I have Windows service and I really need to run one console app (written in C++, but no source) from it. The problem is - service cannot execute other software. And "don't use service" is also not a solution.

The question is - I have exe file. Is there any way that I can call `main` with  of this exe in my current process, like if it is just DLL?

Comment: Why exactly do you believe, that your service cannot execute other software?

Comment: Services can run other programs fine. There is however a problem for interactive programs. If you want interaction then check out Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I would be very grateful, If you could provide me a link, how I can run application from service?

Comment: @Starl1ght: Oh, it's about 20 years (well, 18) since I was doing that stuff. Sorry. What we did then was pretty horrible, we ran Microsoft Word from a service and screen scraped results. I can't recall why that had to be done, it was not my decision. But I was set to do it, with the project manager as my gofer. :) About the only things I remember is that one had to be very careful about security contexts, that the details of that were changing with just about every Windows version, and the (then) Resource Kit had a utility for running a program as a service. Neat. But, just `CreateProcess`?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call an exe as if it were a dll. What you can do though, is run the exe using CreateProcess.

However, services are different, the main code in them generally does nothing but start the service running as a service (basically). So calling it will not do anything except clicking 'start' on the service control manager.

You can run the service, as a service, programmatically though, but there is no way of calling the code inside your own process space. Think of an exe as a black box that you have no control over, except to start it running (either directly by calling it, or indirectly by running it as a service)

Comment: "you cannot call an exe as if it were a dll". It's not a good idea to do so, but are you absolutely certain that this is true? Considering that the file format is the same, including as I recall an export table, I think the burden of proof is on you.

Comment: *"you cannot call an exe as if it were a dll."* - Wait, are you saying that the documentation for [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) is wrong? (*"lpFileName: The name of the module. This can be either a library module (a .dll file) **or an executable module (an .exe file)**."*)

Comment: The biggest problem with calling LoadLibrary on an MSVC++ EXE is that it won't contain `DllMain`, but instead the MSVC++ tsratup code is tied to `main`.

Comment: @MSalters: What's the problem? [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) is *"[a]n **optional** entry point into a dynamic-link library (DLL)."* An executable image can only specify a single entry point, so it cannot both have a `WinMain` and `DllMain`. But since a DLL is distinguishable from an EXE, the loader won't try to call `DllMain` for something, that doesn't have `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` characteristic in its `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`. I don't know whether the loader properly handles relocations for an EXE, though.

Comment: @IInspectable: You're quoting Win32. E.g. a pure resource DLL obviously doesn't need it. An entry point is not at all optional for the MSVC++ runtime though. If you link with the MSVC++ runtime, it takes over the entry point. Your own entry point won't be the Win32 entry point anymore. (That's also why your entry point can be `int main()` instead of `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR , int );` - the MSVC++ entry point does the translatation)

Comment: @MSalters: The entry point is optional as far as loading a DLL is concerned. If the module is not a DLL, the loader simply won't call it. That doesn't mean that your code couldn't just `GetProcAddress` some exported symbol, and call that. That requires, that the EXE does export a symbol to be used for initialization, when dynamically loaded. The issues you named can be worked around. I'm still not sure, how (or if) relocations can be triggered.

Comment: @IInspectable AFAIK the exe contains no entrypoints (ok, main is different, but I doubt its callable from GetProcAddress - never tried that TBH). Unless you explicitly mark functions for dynamic loading, they will not be dynamically loadable, and who marks functions in an exe like that?! Second, its a service, so running main still doesn't do anything, you need to trigger the ServiceStart or Run function like the SCM does.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: *"AFAIK the exe contains no entrypoints"* - **Every** EXE absolutely, positively **must** have an entry point. What should the OS call when creating a process, if there were no entrypoint? *"explicitly mark functions for dynamic loading"* - You cannot mark a function for dynamic loading. You are confusing this with **exporting** a symbol. Besides, the OP doesn't even want to call the entry point, but rather some functionality inside the EXE. The remainder of the previous comment continues to make up facts. Sorry, -1, seeing that you didn't even understand the question.

Comment: @IInspectable well done for ignoring the very next sentence in my answer. Look, if you're so knowedgeable, why don't you answer his question.

Comment: *"Look, if you're so knowedgeable, why don't you answer his question."* - I believe you can deduce this when comprehending the very first comment on the question, a request for clarification. A more important question (that I cannot immediately answer) is: If you are so confused, why did you answer the question?